# Duplicate items in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Create two groups in `ExpandableListView` each with one child. Expand both groups. Remove the child from one group (basically eliminate the group) and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` of adapter (intance of `BaseExpandableListAdapter`).

The duplicate of the child from the remaining group appears. Collapse the only remaining group, the duplicate stays on the screen. Click the group header one more time (re-collapse it), the duplicate goes away. The only solution I found so far is to control all clicks and allow only one group to be expanded at a time. With one real child and one duplicate on screen adapter calls `getChildView()` 4 (?!) times always requesting view for same group 0 and child 0. All responses to adapter callbacks are correct. This is easy to replicate with simple test project(see code below). Any ideas? This is Android 4.4.4.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return MyController.getInstance().getGroupCount();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int i, int i2) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int i, int i2) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (view == null) {LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.getMainContext());
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group, null);
    }

    TextView groupHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    groupHeader.setText(MyController.getInstance().getGroupName(i));

    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int i, int i2, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.getMainContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

   (...set view fields...)

    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i2) {
    return true;
}
```

In the test project there are two buttons to add/remove group `buttonNew` and `buttonRemove` and the code is:

```
public class MyController extends ActionBarActivity {

private static Context mMainContext;
myAdapter adapter;
int groupCount = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mMainContext = MyController.this;
    ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    adapter = new myAdapter();
    expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Button buttonNew = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAddGroup);
    buttonNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            groupCount += 1;
            adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    });
    Button buttonRemove = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRemoveGroup);
    buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            groupCount -= 1;
            adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    });
}

public static Context getInstance()
{
    return mMainContext;
}

public int getGroupCount()
{
    return groupCount;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code showing how MyController.getInstance() is modified during this process of removing child and groups from it?

Comment: Added the code I use in the test project to replicate the issue.